# JS: Understand 1-way and 2-way data binding

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

I am trying to understand one way data binding.  I know Vue is a 2-way data binding framework but if I structure a Vue app where I emit events up to the parent level and pass the new data from the parent down to the children, does that make it '1 way'?

Comment: As you said; you can emit event up to parent and pass data into child components. It's a way to do it. But little bit painful way. I recommended you to use `vuex`. It's a state management lib for `vuejs`. I'm using `vuex` to store data and use them all of my components in the project. If you have a lot of components and have to communicate them, vuex is the solution.

Comment: In vue, a technique like `v-model` is two way, because the data representation can be manipulated from the UI or the component's script. Alternatively, as was mentioned above, Vuex is a centralized store for the state of your app, the "single source of truth" as it's commonly called. The data in state can only be manipulated with mutations, so components cannot manipulate vuex state unless they trigger a mutation synchronously. To access this state data, the component must either use state mapping or a getter.